# Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node':

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I created one datatable at the page `onload` event in a function. On the `onchange` event of a `select` control I need to take that control value and pass it to the function which has the data table.

In that itself my method also there from which I need to take data and set it to datatable. For that I am using the `destroy()` function, which throws an error like

> Failed to execute `insertBefore` on `Node`: The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.

After searching on the internet, I used the `retrieve:true` property, but it is not refreshing with the current data.

Can anyone suggest something regarding this? Below is my sample code.

```js
 function getmailsdata() {
    $.cordys.ajax({
        method: "Getclassifiedmails",
        namespace: "http://schemas.cordys.com/IMSPackage",
        parameters: {
            emailbox:$("#inp_mailbox").val(),
            emailid:'',
            classification:$("#classifiedtype").val(),
            incidentno:'',
            subject:'',
            fromdate:'',
            todate:'',
            body_content:''
        },
        dataType: '* json',
        success: function (result) { 
            /*
            if (Getmaildetailstable != null) {
                Getmaildetailstable.destroy();
            }
            */
            if ( $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#Getmaildetailstable') ) {
                $('#Getmaildetailstable').DataTable().destroy();
                //$('#Getmaildetailstable').html("");
            }
            Getmaildetailstable = $('#Getmaildetailstable').DataTable({  
                "data": ((result.tuple == undefined) ? [] : ((result.tuple.length == undefined) ? [result.tuple] : result.tuple)),
                "columns": [{
                    className: 'dt-body-center',
                    'render': function (data, type, full, meta){
                    return '<input type="checkbox">';
                },
                defaultContent: "",
                "targets": 0,
                }, {
                    "targets": 1,
                    "data": "old.EMAIL.STARRED_FLAG",
                    visible: false,
                }, {
                    "targets": 2,
                    "data": "old.EMAIL.IMPORTANT_FLAG",
                    visible: false,
                }, {
                    "targets": 3,
                    "data": "old.EMAIL.EMAIL_ID",
                    visible: false,
                }, {
                    "targets": 4,
                    "data": "old.EMAIL.EMAILBOX",
                    visible: false,
                }, {
                    "targets": 5,
                    "data": "old.EMAIL.LOGICAL_ID",
                    visible: false,
                }, {
                    "targets": 6,
                     defaultContent: "",
                    "data": "image",render: getStarredflag,
                    visible: true,
                }, {
                    "targets": 7,
                     defaultContent: "",
                    "data": "image",render: getImportantflag,
                    visible: true,
                }, {
                    "targets": 8,
                    "data": "old.EMAIL.SUBJECT",
                    "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                   return '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openmaildetailsfunction()">' + data + '</a>';
                    },
                    visible: true,
                }, {
                    "targets": 9,
                    "data": "old.EMAIL.attachments",
                    visible: false,
                }, {
                    "targets": 10,
                    "data": "old.EMAIL.MAIL_SIZE",
                    visible: false,
                }, {
                    "targets": 11,
                    "data": "old.EMAIL.CREATE_DATE",
                    visible: true,
                }, {
                    "targets": 12,
                    "data": "old.EMAIL.RECEIVE_DATE",
                    visible: false,
                }, {
                    "targets": 13,
                    "data": "old.EMAIL.FROM_ADDRESS",
                    visible: true,
                },  {
                    "targets": 14,
                    "data": "old.EMAIL.TO_ADDRESS",
                    visible: true,
                }, {
                    "targets": 15,
                    "data": "old.EMAIL.INCIDENT_NO",
                    visible: false,
                }, {
                    "targets": 16,
                    "data": "old.EMAIL.CLASSIFICATION_TYPE",
                    visible: false,
                }, {
                    "targets": 17,
                    "data": "image",render: getImg,
                    visible: true,
                }],
                select: {
                    style: 'multi',
                    selector: 'td:first-child'
                }
            });
        },
        async:false,
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        },
        order: [
            [4, 'asc']
        ],
    });
}
window.onload = function () {
    var select = document.getElementById("classifiedtype");
    for(var i = 2011; i >= 1900; --i) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = option.value = i;
        select.add(option, 0);
    }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
  <table id="Getmaildetailstable" class="table table-striped display" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><input name="select_all" value="1" type="checkbox"></th>
        <th>Starredflag</th>
        <th>Importantflag</th>
        <th>Mailid</th>
        <th>Mailbox</th>
        <th>LogicalID</th>
        <th>Starred</th>
        <th>Important</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>attachments</th>
        <th>mailsize</th>
        <th>Created On</th>
        <th>Received On</th>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>To</th>
        <th>Incident_no</th>
        <th>classification</th>
        <th>Attachments</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="form-group  col-md-2">
    <label for="classifiedtype" class="control-label">Classified Type</label>
    <select id="classifiedtype"  class="form-control" onchange="getmailsdata()">
    </select>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: the snippet produces an error: `"message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined"` due to `$.cordys.ajax(.....` (which tells that `$.cordsys` is undefined

Comment: actually that webservice is from our tool,so i was not able to post that method response